# On $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ are these metrics equivalent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\min(1,|a_n-b_n|)$ vs with $\frac{|a_n-b_n|}{n^2(1+|a_n-b_n|)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

How can I show that on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ these two metrics are equivalent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\min(1,|a_n-b_n|)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{|a_n-b_n|}{1+|a_n-b_n|}$?

Actually I'm not even sure whether they're equivalent but my intuition is that since as $a_n$ and $b_n$ get closer $\min(1,|a_n-b_n|)$ and $\frac{|a_n-b_n|}{1+|a_n-b_n|}$ will be nearly the same, and I assume that the $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $1/n^2$ terms wont make a difference. However I don't know how to proceed with the proof. I'd love any kind of hint!

Comment: Could you specify the definition of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ please ? :)

Comment: @Velobos $\displaystyle \mathbb R^\omega := \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \cdots = \prod_\mathbb N \mathbb R$

Comment: I have tried to answer your question, *some* feedback would be appreciated :)

Comment: @MartinR so sorry martin, i really appreciated your answer, i'm gonna accept it and have a couple questions when i finish some other homework that i have :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to show that
$$
 d_1(a, b) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\min(1,|a_n-b_n|)
$$
and
$$
 d_2(a, b) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{|a_n-b_n|}{1+|a_n-b_n|}
$$
generate the same topology on the space $\Bbb R^\omega$ (a countable product of copies of $\Bbb R$, which can be identified with the set of all mappings from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$, i.e. the set of all real-valued sequences.)

It suffices to show that
$$ \tag 1
 \forall r > 0: \exists s > 0: \forall a, b \in \Bbb R^\omega :
 d_1(a, b) < s \implies d_2(a, b) < r
$$
and also the other way around
$$ \tag 2
 \forall r > 0: \exists s > 0: \forall a, b \in \Bbb R^\omega :
 d_2(a, b) < s \implies d_1(a, b) < r \, .
$$

The essential estimate is
$$ \tag 3
 \frac 12 \min (1, x) \le \frac{x}{1+x} \le \min(1, x)
$$
for all $x \ge 0$, which is easy to verify. It shows that for each $n$ the terms
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}\min(1,|a_n-b_n|) \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{|a_n-b_n|}{1+|a_n-b_n|}
$$
become small together. In addition we can use that the series remainders become small independently of $a$ and $b$.

Now let us prove $(1)$. For given $r > 0$, there is an $N$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} < r/2$. Then, using the right estimate in $(3)$,
$$
 d_2(a, b) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{|a_n-b_n|}{1+|a_n-b_n|} + \frac r 2\\
\le \sum_{n=1 }^N \frac{1}{n^2} \min(1, |a_n - b_n| + \frac r 2 \\
\le 2^N \sum_{n=1 }^N \frac{1}{2^n} \min(1, |a_n - b_n| + \frac r 2 \\
\le 2^N d_1(a, b) + \frac r 2
$$
so that
$$
 d_1(a, b) <  \frac{r}{2 \cdot 2^N} \implies d_2(a, b) < r \, .
$$

The proof of $(2)$ is a bit easier: From the left estimate in $(3)$ and $2^{n+1} \ge n^2$ we get that
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}\min(1,|a_n-b_n|) \le \frac{2}{n^2} \frac{2|a_n-b_n|}{1+|a_n-b_n|}
$$
and therefore
$$
 d_1(a, b) \le 4 d_2(a, b) \, .
$$

---

*Remark:* The metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ are *not strongly* equivalent. If we choose $a_n = 0$, and $b_n= 1$ if $n=k$ and $b_n = 0$ otherwise then
$$ 
d_1(a, b) = \frac{1}{2^k} \, , \, d_2(a, b) = \frac{1}{k^2}
$$
which shows that there is no constant $\beta > 0$ with the property
$$
 \forall a, b \in \Bbb R^\omega: d_2(a, b) \le \beta d_1(a, b) \, .
$$

Comment: thanks you so much for your answer! it clears up a lot! i went through it 3 times now, and i can't figure out how i could have thought of it from the start. can i ask you what resources you might recommend for someone to tackle problems like these? if you have a nice exercise book or something else in mind it would be fantastic! also do u think working on an inequalities book (like the one by Hardy) would be worthwhile?

Comment: @StupidQuestionsInc: Unfortunately I do not have any recommendations. I am doing this just for fun, my university career is long ago.

Comment: i guessed that when i saw ur impressive stackoverflow profile :) thanks anyway for your help, i'll try to see if i can find better sources however to deal with such problems !